# The dependency microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc 1.0.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp, Version=v1.0

Tags: asp.net-core

Trying to create an ASP.NET Core project given that it has just reached RTM. I created a new project using the Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 template called 'ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)'. I then went to the Nuget Package Manager and updated all the `package.json` packages to 1.0.0. Visual Studio fails to restore the package with the error in the title of this post.

Here is the `project.json` after updating Nuget Packages:

```
{ 
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

The output from the Nuget Package Manager:

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with
>   netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
>         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
>         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you remember to install: .NET Core Tools for Visual Studio?  You can get that [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/3/8/A38489F3-9777-41DD-83F8-2CBDFAB2520C/DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe).

Take a look at Scott Hanselman's [Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/).

Comment: Yeah, beat me to it by about 2 minutes: was just installing it. Can confirm that it fixes the issue.

Comment: Looks like you need VS 2015 (Express or any version above that) to install the core tools.

Comment: What if I'm on Linux?

Comment: This does not solve the issue for me, any other suggestions?

Comment: Me too having problems even after installing the tools preview 2

Comment: I just had to run "dotnet restore" again, and the problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

NetCoreApp needs to be of type 'platform'.

Answer (score 0):

The target needs to be plattform:
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
"version": "1.0.0",
"type": "platform"
},

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest version of .Net Core 1.0 seems to have done the trick for me on my Windows environment.

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3703

You can get the latest version here.

https://www.microsoft.com/net

Answer (score 0):

I had to add these NuGet feeds (*not sure if both are needed*) and then just rebuild:

```
https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json
https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-cli/api/v3/index.json
```

I did this in Visual Studio:

- Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources